# Is this a missed optimization opportunity or not

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59290242/10147399) answer. Code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <utility>
void printImpl(...);

std::atomic<bool> printLog = false;

class Log {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  const auto& operator<<(T&& t) {
    if (printLog) {
      ulog.active = true;
      return ulog << std::forward<T>(t);
    } else {
      ulog.active = false;
      return ulog;
    }
  }

 private:
  struct unchecked_log {
    template <typename T>
    const auto& operator<<(T&& t) const {
      if (active) {
        printImpl(std::forward<T>(t));
      }
      return *this;
    }
    bool active{false};
  };
  unchecked_log ulog{};
};

// Instead of the macro. Doesn't break backward compatibility
Log LOG;

void test(bool) { LOG << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 8 << 9 << 10; }
```

In essence, the code either ignores or logs all the data. The idea was to record the `atomic<bool>` in a regular `bool` which can be optimized out more easily. I thought most compilers could easily optimize out the `if (active)` part since there is no way it can change between calls. [Turns out](https://godbolt.org/z/4kKH5N) though, most compilers do inline the function call to `unchecked_log::operator<<` but do not optimize out the branching. Is there something preventing this optimization? Would it be illegal.

Comment: `Log::operator <<` depends on `printLog` though, which is a global variable. The compiler will expect that to change, you could use a constant if it really can't. And it's the same `ulog` object both ways, I think the standard might forbid that "optimisation" of `ulog::operator <<`, what if there was two threads for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOG` is a global variable with external linkage. Therefore `printImpl`'s definition in another translation unit can reach it and can potentially modify `LOG.ulog.active` between calls.

Make `LOG` a local variable in `test` and the repeated checks will be consolidated into one at the entry of `test` or leave `LOG` where it is and make it `static`, so a different compilation unit containing `printImpl`'s definition cannot reach this translation unit's instance.

As mentioned in a comment below, alternatively let `operator<<` return by copy, so that the instance it returns (now a temporary) is unreachable for `printImpl`.

---

Note that the accessibility (`private`, etc.) of `ulog` and `ulog.active` does not matter. As soon as `printImpl` is able to obtain a pointer or reference to the instance of relevance, `private` does not protect from modification no matter what. Here are few examples of how that is possible (non-exhaustive):

1. Calling `operator<<` on `LOG` which may now change `LOG.ulog.active` based on an intervening modification of `printLog` or by `const_cast`ing the result
2. Calling the defaulted copy/move assignment operators
3. (since this is a standard-layout class) `reinterpret_cast` `LOG` to a reference to its `ulog` member
4. (since the classes are trivially copyable) `memcpy` a different state into `LOG`
5. placement-new a new instance of `Log` into `LOG`, which will make previous references reference the new object automatically, because `Log` satisfies the conditions for that
6. etc.

Comment: `LOG` has to be a global variable, but returning `LOG.ulog` by value [does enable the optimization](https://godbolt.org/z/mA-eg5) too.

Comment: `printImpl` could call `LOG.operator<<` and `const_cast` the result to change it's member. That's why returning by value enables the optimization. But returning by value had nothing to do with the `reinterpret_cast` case you mentioned in the answer. So compilers shouldn't have enabled the optimization?

Comment: @Ayxan But, every time you write a `const_cast`, a kitten dies. Never do that. `reinterpret_cast` is not much better..

Comment: @Ayxan The point is that the *`unchecked_log` instance* returned by-value is not reachable by `printImpl`, it has no way of getting a pointer or reference to it. If it has a pointer or reference, then it basically doesn't matter how you tried to protect yourself with `private` and friends, there are ways to modify members even if you don't have access to their names. (It doesn't matter for this case, I just mentioned it as an aside.)

Comment: @walnut I think `reinterpret_cast` method wouldn't work because `Log::unchecked_log` is a private class, so there is no way to name it in `reinterpret_cast<Log::unchecked_log*>(&LOG)`, hence the `const_cast` method was the only thing preventing the optimization.

Comment: @Ayxan You can `decltype` for it though. Anyway, I believe walnut means that you can `reinterpret_cast<bool*>` to access the member if you get an instance of `unchecked_log`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're right. So the `printImpl` could do something like `auto l = LOG << 1;
    auto& ulog = *(reinterpret_cast<decltype(l)*>(&LOG));
    ulog.active = true;` So what compilers did was illegal?

Comment: @Ayxan If you return by-value or use a `LOG` without external linkage, then `printImpl` has no way of obtaining a reference to the instance of relevance, so it cannot use that. These hypotheticals are for the case where you keep using the global `LOG.ulog` with external linkage. Therefore the optimization is valid.

Comment: @walnut In [this](https://godbolt.org/z/cGWYRb) example `LOG` is still a global variable. So `printImpl` could still do all the evil things you mentioned in the answer and I mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291618/is-this-a-missed-optimization-opportunity-or-not#comment104788826_59291693) previous comment. But `if (active)` seems to be optimized out. Why is it optimized then? Am I getting something wrong? I am really sorry if there is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: @Ayxan Yes `printImpl` can modfiy `LOG.ulog.active`, but that is not what you keep using in `test`. The first `<<` returns another `unchecked_log` instance by value, which is then manifested as a temporary in the `LOG << ...` expression in `test` and on which then the other `<<` are called. `printImpl` cannot reach this temporary instance if you don't hand it a reference to it explicitly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've written `const_cast` when I have a pair of functions, one of which takes a const pointer and returns another const pointer which is related, and another which takes a non-const pointer and returns a similar non-const pointer.  The non-const calls the const function, and const-casts the result.  No kittens harmed.

Comment: @walnut Oh, now I get it. Thank you very much for the effort and time you spent on this question.

Comment: @MartinBonner Well, as long as none of the objects you cast const off were originally declared as const (can be hard to know) and they are not modified, then there's no UB and the kittens live. I'd still call it questionable practice though.

Comment: @Ayxan Note however that since you are calling `printImpl` first, before constructing the return value, there will actually be two branches (see the assembly). It is not entirely optimal. To make it optimal you should first make a copy of `ulog`, that you then return later or make `ulog` entirely local to the `operator<<` overload of `Log`.